# Strange error on Xcode : parse issue Unknown type name 'plementation'

Tags: xcode, ios4, xcode4

on the line:

```
@implementation  AccountCreateViewController
@synthesize profileFacebook;
@synthesize facebook;
```

Xcode 4 says :Error  parse issue Unknown type name 'plementation' 
There are a lot of parse issue after that.
But the project works on an iPhone.

I really don't know what it is... I try to convert the file in CR/LF (it was LF before), it didn't work.

ps: [image: a screenshot]

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuilding? I know XCode4 to be really flaky with false or stale parse errors. If it builds and runs on the device then it could be one of these flukes where the parser is struggling to keep up with the project. Typically these go away after a clean rebuild or restart of XCode.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem!  The project compiles and runs on the simulator, but then about a second or two later, it'll pop up all those errors.  I tried cleaning the project and rebuilding but it happens every time.  I am using LLVM 2.1

Comment: @Cliff I tried that and delete everything, didn't work :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I might have fixed it.  It seems that LLVM Clang doesn't like UTF-8 BOM encoding.

See this Code Issue on the Sudzc website.

http://code.google.com/p/sudzc/issues/detail?id=27

For my own project, I opened up the offending files with TextWrangler and re-saved them with "Western (Mac OS Roman) encoding.  So far I haven't gotten any further problems from LLVM/Clang.

Comment: Rah, good I find it. My files come from a php script to build the root of a project. I put them in utf8 + CRLF in TextWrangler. Thx

Comment: Thanks, I daren't imagine how much time I would have wasted on this. Also, +1 for UTF8.

Comment: I had a similar issue and got here, but the answer in my case was that I had to rename my file to `.mm` because of an interaction between my code and a library.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error but in my `.h` file. I fixed it simply by a forward declaration as:

```
#import "MyCustomClassThatGaveParseError.h" // existed before the error
@class MyCustomClassThatGaveParseError; // added to remove the weird error
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not a "solution" but that's how I solved my problem anyway. I changed the base SDK from OS X 10.8 back to OS X 10.7 and everything works fine now.